# CLOUDBEES ERROR: RequestExpired - Request has expired

Tags: cloud, cloudbees

I have downloaded **cloudbees skd 1.5.0** and am now running the Bees Console on **windows 7** the first time, by using the command **bees** and the result is as follows:

```
Updating Bees SDK. This may take a while
# CloudBees SDK version: 1.5.0
# CloudBees Driver version: 1.3.6
Installing plugin: org.cloudbees.sdk.plugins:ant-plugin:1.3.0

You have not created a CloudBees configuration profile, let's create one now...
Enter your default CloudBees API end point [us | eu]: eu
Enter your CloudBees account email address: mvdev@myapp.com
Enter your CloudBees account password:mypass

ERROR: RequestExpired - Request has expired
```

please advise why i am getting this error, and how to fix it.

Comment: Did you try it again? Could have been a temporary problem with time taken to start/complete the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This implies that the timestamp used by the client (SDK) to sign the API request was wrong.  If the request is signed with a time that is in the future or more than 4 hours in the past, then you will get this error. This is mostly likely caused by time misconfigurations on the computer sending the request.  You should verify that the system time and timezone is properly set in your operating system.

Comment: what command should i use to know server time, maybe my timezone is in future for the server.